# Ionic 2 network.type = null

Tags: ionic, typescript, ionic2, angular

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação em ionic 2 ts, porem quando tento verificar se está conectado na internet ele me retorna null.
Meu código

```js
import { Network } from '@ionic-native/network';


@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html',
  providers: [ProviderAccessApi]
})
export class HomePage {
  user : string;
  pass:string;

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public providerAPI:ProviderAccessApi, private platform: Platform, public alertCtrl : AlertController, public network : Network) {
      console.log('HomePage carragada com sucesso')
      alert(network.type);
  }
```

Como posso arrumar ?

Comment: Você seguiu [esses passos](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/network/)?

Comment: Sim, porem coloquei só o  network.type, sem o conecta desconecta... Mas coloquei no appmodule tudo...

Comment: Agora deu certo, testei no iphone, não no emulador